# Method call: Attempted to call method on null context object?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

My Stack Trace Log

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "instrucor.getInstructorId()" (template: "views/update" - line 39, col 14)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
6-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted

2023-01-06T09:29:51.435+02:00 ERROR 18336 --- [nio-8071-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "instrucor.getInstructorId()" (template: "views/update" - line 39, col 14)] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getInstructorId() on null context object
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.throwIfNotNullSafe(MethodReference.java:154) ~[spring-expression-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
```

I check my spring version 3.00 and thymeleaf version 3.1.

My  Html + thymeleaf

```
<div class="mb-3 mt-3">  
   <label class ="form-label"> Instructor: </label>
   <select th:field="${course.instructor}" name="instructor" class="form-select"> 
    
    <option th:each="instructor:${listInstructor}" th:text="${instructor.getfirstName()} + ' ' +${instructor.getlastName()}"
             th:value="${instrucor.getInstructorId()}"> </option>
   </select>
   </div>
```

In mySql i have Instructor

Also my Controller

```
@GetMapping ("/update")
    public String updateCourse (Model model, Long courseId) {
        Course course = courseService.loadCourseBycourseId(courseId);
        List <Instructor> instructors = instructorService.fetchInstrucotr();
        model.addAttribute("course", course);
        model.addAttribute("listInstructor", instructors);
        return "views/update";
    }
    
    @PostMapping ("/save")
    public String saveCourse (Course course) {
        courseService.createOrUpdateCourse(course);
        return "redirect:/courses/index";
    }
```

Without this instructor fields in html, ma page loaded without problem

Comment: This looks like a typo: `th:value="${instrucor.getInstructorId()}"`. I assume that should be `th:value="${instructor.getInstructorId()}"` - check the spelling: `instructor` not `instrucor`.

Comment: Side note: It is more usual to just use the field names - so `${instructor.instructorId}` - assuming you are following the naming conventions for JavaBeans getters. Thymeleaf will take your `instructorId` and look for a method called `getInstructorId()` based on the field name.

Comment: real tnx, two days, i search problem, and this problem was 1 later. Not instrucor --> instructor. I'll be more careful now. More and more careful, tank you Andrew